# Playing Audio and Video of a mp4 file separately using AVFoundation Framework

Tags: objective-c, ios4, avfoundation

I have developed a media player using AVFoundation for iOS. I am using AVPlayer to play the audio-video files (eg. a mp4 file). It seems quiet simple to play the file using AVPlayer, by directly calling the play, pause APIs.

Now I want to separate the audio and video and play them as individual entities simultaneously. I want to do this because, I may do some editing to the audio or video track, and then play the file.

I can separate the two using AVAssetTracks, but I dont know how to play the tracks. Also, I would like to play the two tracks simultaneously, so that no AVSync problem occurs.

Please guide me how to achieve this target, i.e. audio and video rendering with no AVSync problem.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this would be to have multiple player items.  I would create a playerItem with all the tracks in their original form (ie the mp4 file).  Then create another asset using AVMutableComposition (a subclass of AVAsset).  This allows you to put only certain tracks into the composition (ie the audio track only).  When you want to play the audio only, play the playerItem (AVPLayer setCurrentItem:) that has the mutable composition with the audio only track.  When you want to play the video only, play the playerItem that has the mutable composition with the video only track.  When you want to play both in sync, play the playerItem with the original asset.

I'm assuming you want to play the edited versions in sync.  For that you will have to create another AVMutableComposition and add all of the edited tracks.  Then call setCurrentItem: with the newly created AVMutableComposition.

If all you are trying to do is edit the different tracks, and never have to play them by themselves, you can do this with one single AVMutableComposition.  Just add an audio and video AVMutableCompositionTrack and edit until your hearts content. They will always play in sync no matter how much you edit them separately (assuming your editing logic is correct).  Just make sure you don't try to edit while playing.  For that, you must create a copy and edit the copy.